# Using \ifdefined to show/hidden content

Tags: spacing, macros

I'm using `\newcommand` and `\ifdefined` in the following way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\showcomment}{}
\newcommand{\scomment}[1]{\ifdefined\showcomment\textcolor{blue} {\small\bfseries[ #1 --someone ]}\else\fi}
\begin{document}
some content
\scomment{comment}
some content
\end{document}
```

[image]

In this way, I can uncomment `\newcommand{\showcomment}{}` to avoid showing inline comments in pdf. But the problem is that, when doing this, it will leave **two spaces** between `some content`:

[image]

If I comment out `\scomment{comment}`, only one space is showing between adjacent contents. But this is apparently not the desired way since there will be many of those commands.

Is there a way to achieve the same functionality while avoiding double spaces?

Comment: Now you're enjoying the new LaTeX 2e, why not update your syntax to remove obsolete font commands such as `\bf`? And it never did take an argument .... `\small` doesn't take an argument either.

Comment: I guess it would be more natural to define a boolean `\if...` (or an `etoolbox` toggle) directly instead of `\ifdefined\showcomment`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I wouldn't trust this, myself. Why not use [`fixme`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fixme) or [`todonotes`](https://ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) or one of the many other packages designed for this? You want to reinvent the wheel? OK. But, really, is your hexagonal design honestly going to do the make the cut? Sure, the round shape is old hat, a bit boring, what the old folks use, but, in the end, maybe the designer knew a thing or two about getting the job done?*

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\scomment}[1]{\ifdefined\showcomment\textcolor{blue}{\small\bfseries[ #1 --someone ]}\else\unskip\fi}
\begin{document}
some content
\scomment{comment}
some content

\newcommand{\showcomment}{}%
some content
\scomment{comment}
some content
\end{document}
```

[image: spacing facilities]

`\bf`, `\it`, `\tt` and the rest of it were made obsolete by the introduction of NFSS with LaTeX 2e and ought not be used with the LaTeX format. Some classes do not even continue to support them.

None of those commands or their current equivalents or any of the font size commands take arguments.

```
\small{hi} bye
```

is just the same as

```
\small hi bye
```

and will make the rest of your document use a smaller font size, until you change it back.

Comment: The fix works for me! As for the two packages you mentioned (`fixme` and `todonotes`), do they support multiple users so that different comment styles are showing in a collaborative document?

Comment: @chaonan99 From the `fxime` documentation: "FiXme
provides support for collaborative annotating by allowing
you to “register” several authors." But I'm sure `todonotes` can do a similar thing.

Comment: @chaonan99 I've never used `todonotes`, so I can't say, but `fixme` definitely does this. I've used the multiple-author-tracking myself and it worked great.

Comment: I'd recommend using the marginnote layout with fixme and setting innerlayout to something like noinnerlayout (don't have a pc with me), this has the advantage that now fxote can be used everywhere, at the cost of writing on top of each other if used twice on the same line (but there is counter measures for that). I use fixme for all document notes on projects that I edit and use it for author communication using the author key

Comment: @daleif Yes, that's similar to the approach I've used, too.

Comment: @cfr you can easily add an extra option to fxnote such that you can manually move the marginnote up and down.

Comment: @daleif Yes, as I say, I like `fixme` a lot and it has worked well for me.

Comment: `\let\showcomment=\UndefINeD` `some content\leaders\hbox{X}\hskip 4cm \scomment{comment} some content` `\def\showcomment{}` `some content\leaders\hbox{X}\hskip 4cm \scomment{comment} some content`

Where have all the `\leaders` gone?
Long time passing?
Where have all the `\leaders` gone?
Long time ago?
Where have all the `\leaders` gone?
`\unskip` picked them everyone.
When will they ever learn?
When will they ever learn?

Answer (score 1):

There are commands in LaTeX, like `\label` or `\index`, whose occurrence in the .tex-input should not affect the look of those passages of text that LaTeX is about to typeset while processing the `\label`-command  or `\index`-command in question.

Internally these macros use `\@bsphack`..`\@esphack` in order to ensure that spaces after them will be ignored in case there also were spaces before them.

Unfortunately the algorithm gets disturbed when you have a sequence of  `\label`- or `\index`-commands.

In the example below I implemented a variant which seems to not get disturbed.

Besides this I decided to implement forking depending on `\showcomment` being defined in a way which cannot be fooled by imbalanced `\if..`/`else`/`\fi` within the argument of `\showcomment`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}

%--------------------------------------------------------
% This just draws a grid so you can with monospaced fonts
% like \texttt see the amount of horizontal spaces
%
% This is quick and dirty. Don't use it for produtive
% work.
%
% \uglygridphantom{<width>}{<height>}{<linecolor>}{<background color>}
%
\newcommand\uglygridphantom[4]{%
%  \leavevmode
  \rlap{%
    \vbox to 0cm{%
      \kern\dp\strutbox
      \kern-.5\baselineskip
      \noindent\fboxsep=0cm
      \setbox\csname @tempboxa\endcsname=\hbox{W}%   
      \kern-.5\wd\csname @tempboxa\endcsname
      \colorbox#4{%
        \vbox to \numexpr#2+1\relax\baselineskip{%
          \leaders\hbox{%
            \hbox to \numexpr#1+1\relax\wd\csname @tempboxa\endcsname{%
              \setbox\csname @tempboxa\endcsname=\hbox{W\kern-\fboxrule}%
              \leaders\hbox{%
                \textcolor#3{%
                  \rule{.5\wd\csname @tempboxa\endcsname}{\fboxrule}%
                  \rule[-.5\baselineskip]{\fboxrule}{\baselineskip}%
                  \rule{.5\wd\csname @tempboxa\endcsname}{\fboxrule}%
                }%
              }\hfill
            }%
          }\vfill
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
%--------------------------------------------------------



%\newcommand{\showcomment}{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\scomment}[1]{%
  \my@bsphack
  \ifdefined\showcomment
    \expandafter\my@esphack\expandafter\@firstofone
  \else
    \expandafter\my@esphack\expandafter\@gobble
  \fi
  {%
    \textcolor{blue}{%
      {%
        %% Turn off the font changes as they 
        %% disturb my nice little grid :-)
        %\small\bfseries\selectfont
        [ #1 --someone ]%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\newskip\mysavsk
\newcommand*\my@bsphack{%
  \relax
  \ifhmode\mysavsk\lastskip\@savsk\lastskip\@savsf\spacefactor\fi
}%
\newcommand*\my@esphack{%
  \relax
  \ifhmode
    \spacefactor\@savsf
    \ifdim\@savsk>\z@
      \ifdim\lastskip=\z@\nobreak\hskip\z@skip\fi
      \nobreak\hskip-\mysavsk
      \nobreak\hskip\mysavsk
      \ignorespaces
    \fi
  \fi
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\parindent=0ex
\parskip=0ex

\let\showcomment=\UnDeFinED
\rmfamily\selectfont
Now\verb|\showcomment| is undefined:
\ttfamily\selectfont

\uglygridphantom{69}{2}{[rgb]{0.5059,0.5059,0.5059}}{[rgb]{0.9294,0.9294,0.9294}}%
some content
\scomment{commentA} \scomment{commentB}
\scomment{commentC} \scomment{commentD}
some content

\vspace*{2\baselineskip}
\def\showcomment{}
\rmfamily\selectfont
Now\verb|\showcomment| is defined:
\ttfamily\selectfont

\uglygridphantom{69}{2}{[rgb]{0.5059,0.5059,0.5059}}{[rgb]{0.9294,0.9294,0.9294}}%
some content
\scomment{commentA} \scomment{commentB}
\scomment{commentC} \scomment{commentD}
some content

\vspace*\baselineskip
\rmfamily\selectfont
I hope that did the trick.

\end{document}
```

[image]